# Return Application.OnKey to previous state

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm using Application.OnKey to run some macros easily in a spreadsheet. When the spreadsheet exits, it releases the keys by setting them to nothing.

However, there may be other spreadsheets open at the time that want to use the same keys, so I'd like to be able to set the OnKey to what it was when the spreadsheet opened.

Can I get the current procedure set to a OnKey (if one exists) so I can set it back later?

I'm using Excel 2010, but could move to 2013 or 2016 if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `OnKey` functions at the application level, you must do some special housekeeping.

Rather than have each workbook attempt to save and restore other workbook's `OnKey` settings, use the workbook Activate Event to clear all current `OnKey` settings and establish the `OnKey` environment for that workbook.

As you shift focus among a group of open workbooks, each workbook sets up the environment it needs.

When you Open a workbook, it will run both the Open Event as well as the Activate event.  So the environment setup will work in that case as well.